# Key passphase request without running ssh agent.

Tags: git, ssh

I open Windows `cmd`(not Git Bash). Go to project with `.git` directory in it. I run `git push` and receive the: `Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':`. This means I have ssh agent running and key added to it.

But when I run `ssh-add -l` I get `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` which telling me that I have no agent running.

How is it possible to run `git push` without ssh agent running? Or does it started immediately for git push command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompt means:

1. Your key is password protected
2. SSH could find it in the default path but it was not loaded in the agent (if any)

There is no need for a key to be loaded in the agent to be used. It looks like this is your case. SSH looks into `$HOME/.ssh` or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` on Windows. You can run `ssh -vvv <URL>` to follow up the trace.

To make sure you have loaded your key, use `ssh-add -L`. This will list the keys you have loaded, or display an error message if no agent can be found. In order to load your key during the time of the session (not persistent), use `ssh-agent bash` then `ssh-add`.

Comment: I wasn't able to run `ssh -vvv <URL>` successfully. But anyway thank you for clarification.